# text in align-environment

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, align

Is there a way to coordinate the space here?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, titlepage]{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
P\textcolor{red}{_n} &= 1000 - {q_S} - q_{M\textcolor{red}{_n}} \\
\intertext{\center{bzw.}} \
P\textcolor{blue}{_h} &= 1000 - {q_S} - q_{M\textcolor{blue}{_h}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What should `\center` do? The `\center` command should never be used in the body of the document, but, if ever, only for defining new environments.

Comment: rather than `\intertext` (which is intended to start the text at the left margin), why not just make this another line in the aligned display, coded as `&\qquad\text{bzw.}\\ `?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have discovered that `\center` is a very dangerous command that can be only used, if ever, in definitions of other environments.

What you need is `\centering` (or a different method altogether). With `\shortintertext` (requires `mathtools`) you get less space.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, titlepage]{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
P_{\textcolor{red}{n}} &= 1000 - {q_S} - q_{M_{\textcolor{red}{n}}} \\
\intertext{bzw.}
P_{\textcolor{blue}{h}} &= 1000 - {q_S} - q_{M_{\textcolor{blue}{h}}}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
P_{\textcolor{red}{n}} &= 1000 - {q_S} - q_{M_{\textcolor{red}{n}}} \\
\intertext{\centering bzw.}
P_{\textcolor{blue}{h}} &= 1000 - {q_S} - q_{M_{\textcolor{blue}{h}}}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
P_{\textcolor{red}{n}} &= 1000 - {q_S} - q_{M_{\textcolor{red}{n}}} \\
\shortintertext{\centering bzw.}
P_{\textcolor{blue}{h}} &= 1000 - {q_S} - q_{M_{\textcolor{blue}{h}}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that with `_{\textcolor{red}{n}}` instead of `\textcolor{red}{_n}` the subscript is properly kerned.

The different method altogether uses `array`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, titlepage]{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{array}{r@{}>{{}}l}
P_{\textcolor{red}{n}} &= 1000 - {q_S} - q_{M_{\textcolor{red}{n}}} \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\text{bzw.}}\\
P_{\textcolor{blue}{h}} &= 1000 - {q_S} - q_{M_{\textcolor{blue}{h}}}
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, titlepage]{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\P\textcolor{red}{_n} &= 1000 - {q_S} - q_{M\textcolor{red}{_n}} \\
\intertext{\hfill{bzw.}\hfill\mbox{}}
P\textcolor{blue}{_h} &= 1000 - {q_S} - q_{M\textcolor{blue}{_h}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]